# ScrollViewer - scroll does not work with images inside ScrollViewer

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, scrollviewer

I have a ScrollViewer, inside of which is some content. The problem is that the scroll doesn't work  properly. When you scroll the content with your finger and then release, the scrollable area always snaps back to the top. It just bounces like elastic, and won't stay at the bottom where you scrolled it to.

```
<Grid Name="DetailPane" Margin="0,0,0,65" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="White" Opacity="0.85">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button Margin="0" Padding="0" Click="CloseDetailPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Source="images\appbar.close.rest.small.png" Width="20" Height="20"></Image>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="contentScrollViewer" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Padding="10,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="titleTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF2B2929" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <Image x:Name="contentThumbnail" Source="bild.jpg" Visibility="Visible" Width="400" Height="300" Margin="10" />
                    <TextBlock Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="statusTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF2B2929" />
                    <HyperlinkButton Padding="0,5,0,10" x:Name="WikipeadiaLink" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="More on Wikipedia" TargetName="_blank"  NavigateUri="" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="18" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I've actually had a similar problem before, which I managed to solve with help from Stack Overflow... and yet, here I am again, asking for help on the same topic... 
thanks heaps!

UPDATE:
Based on suggestions, I removed the `StackPanels` and replaced them with `Grids`. The formatting is perfect, but I still have the same scroll problem! The content still snaps back to the beginning!

```
<Grid Name="DetailPane" Margin="0,0,0,65" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="White" Opacity="0.85">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0"  Margin="0" Padding="0" Click="CloseDetailPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
            <Button.Content>
                <Image Source="images\appbar.close.rest.small.png" Width="20" Height="20"></Image>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="contentScrollViewer" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Padding="10,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="titleTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF2B2929" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <Image x:Name="contentThumbnail" Grid.Row="1" Source="bild.jpg" Visibility="Visible" Width="400" Height="300" Margin="10" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"  Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="statusTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF2B2929" />
                <HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="3" Padding="0,5,0,10" x:Name="WikipeadiaLink" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="More on Wikipedia" TargetName="_blank"  NavigateUri="" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="18" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer> 
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved this, in the end, was adding a static height to the `ScrollViewer`. I realise noone could have seen this as I omitted the part of the code that shows that this is inside a `PivotItem`.

According to this discussion: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/84933.aspx  a ScrollViewer stops working properly when it is inside a Pivot, unless it has a static height defined.

Infuriating!

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the `stackPanel`, try replacing it with something else like `Grid`.

Try this, I removed a redundant grid and added stretched alignment for the scroll viewer:

```
<Grid Name="DetailPane" Margin="0,0,0,65" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="White" Opacity="0.85">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0"  Click="CloseDetailPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button.Content>
            <Image Source="images\appbar.close.rest.small.png" Width="20" Height="20"></Image>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>


        <ScrollViewer x:Name="contentScrollViewer" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Padding="10,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="titleTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF2B2929" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <Image x:Name="contentThumbnail" Grid.Row="1" Source="bild.jpg" Visibility="Visible" Width="400" Height="300" Margin="10" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"  Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="statusTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF2B2929" />
                <HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="3" Padding="0,5,0,10" x:Name="WikipeadiaLink" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="More on Wikipedia" TargetName="_blank"  NavigateUri="" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="18" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Do you mean the stackpanel outside or inside the ScrollViewer?

Comment: The inner one primarily, but I'd go for replacing both of them. StackPanel's adjust to the available size, and thus don't overflow the screen size, which makes the scrollviewer out of work. Also, stackpanels aren't optimal for virtualization. I'll recommend reading up on how StackPanel and Grid are different.

And oh, DockPanel and Windows Phone don't really have anything to do with eachother ;-)

Comment: @WillGill: As Claus already said, you should read about _stackPanel_, the issue with the _scrollViewer_ is very common.

Comment: thanks for the tips gents. I'm working on swapping them out for Grids right now... will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I removed the StackPanels, and now have a beautifully formatted display using Grids - but I still have exactly the same scroll problem... I have added the new XAML above...

Comment: @MichaelS thanks for that - I tried your code: the layout looks visually the same, but I still have the problem with the scroll... when I scroll the content up, and release, it snaps back to the starting position... very strange!!

Comment: @WillGill: Weird.. I can't ran it over here currently, i will try to help you further later. Sorry

Comment: @WillGill: Is your Grid is part of Pivot or panorama? See the following [discussion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/luc/archive/2010/11/22/preventing-the-pivot-or-panorama-controls-from-scrolling.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+msdn%2FVbhA+%28MSDN+Blogs%29)

Comment: @MichaelS Yes, it is - but there are no interactive elements inside the scrollViewer - just static text and images... there is no problem getting the scrollViewer to respond to gesture input - the content moves when you scroll... the problem is just that the content always snaps back to the starting position instead of staying where you scrolled it to.